# Python task queue alternatives and frameworks

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

There seem to be different implementations of [task/job queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_queue) for Python 3:

1. [Celery](https://github.com/celery/celery), popular but apparently unmaintained and stale;
2. [RQ](https://github.com/nvie/rq), of which I have little information;
3. [TaskTiger](https://github.com/closeio/tasktiger), similarly to RQ I know little about it;
4. [Huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey) , similarly to RQ I know little about it;
5. [WorQ](https://github.com/millerdev/WorQ/) had its last update in 2016.

Then there are “cloud” based solutions like [Google’s Task Queue API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/) or [AWS’s Cloud Watch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html), but that’s more of a last resort.

For my project I am looking for a *stable* and *active* task queue implementation. I’ve used Celery for the past year, but the lack of support and non-attention to existing bugs is worrisome.

What alternatives exist?

Comment: Related writeup with more links: https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html And here is a collection of queuing frameworks: http://queues.io/

Comment: Celery is neither unmaintained nor stale. Issues are being closed. It is still the de-facto standard in the Python industry. Not saying is the only valid alternative, just saying it is maintained and robust.

Comment: @Akhorus: AFAIK left the maintainer of Celery the project, and it has been sitting around and accumulating issues without support (ICQ, Github, mailing lists) for months. There’s been a flurry of activity over the past few weeks, and it looks like somebody else has taken over the maintenance.

Comment: That is not true... Just look at how many issues have been closed, and they are about to make a stable release 4.2.0 (it is in the RC3 state now).

Comment: Development for windows stopped at Celery 3 so you could say its "stale" if thats what you meant

Answer (score 78):

I wrote [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io) specifically because of my increasing frustration with Celery having used it professionally for years. Check out the [motivation](https://dramatiq.io/motivation.html) page the "why" and a feature comparison between Dramatiq, Celery and RQ. Some highlights:

- actively developed and used in production
- great docs
- automatic retries
- code auto-reload
- locks and rate limiting
- redis and rabbitmq support

Comment: I’ve been using Dramatiq for [Bookalope](https://bookalope.net/) now for about a month, and it works like a charm. Great work, Bogdan 

Comment: Dramatiq is really good - simple, flexible, powerfull

Comment: Used Dramatiq in a few projects and definitely recommend it

Comment: Task Prioritization, auto-retry are now supported in Celery - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/faq.html#does-celery-support-task-priorities

Comment: Hey @Bogdan Pop can you tell me how can i run it as a daemon in linux based environment ? Or anyother suitable way to deploy it in production ?

Comment: @BogdanPopa Does it support Windows OS, because currently I am using celery for windows and I am having trouble with ConnectionResetError[10054].

Comment: @sattva_venu yes, Dramatiq does support Windows.

Comment: @BogdanPopa how about remote system configuration, can we mention another host's IP address and trigger the worker in different machine using Dramatiq?

Comment: Really want dramatiq to work. I'm frustrated as hell with celery, it isn't reliable at all to run in production.

Comment: I'm looking for celery alternatives, but  revoking a task is one of our functionality which i couldn't see in dramatiq.

Comment: Any guidance for the error `dramatiq_abort missing key word argument "client"` as from your cookbook page https://dramatiq.io/cookbook.html on the abort section...

Answer (score 14):

One new alternative is [django-carrot](https://github.com/chris104957/django-carrot), which came about due to our requirement for a lightweight alternative to Celery, while still providing support for RabbitMQ (I think the other alternatives you've mentioned are all based on Redis)

Django-carrot is still under development but is expected to go into production at my company in the next few weeks

**Disclaimer** - I'm the author of django-carrot

Comment: Thanks! How’s that coming along, and would it run standalone (i.e. without django) as well, or with [Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid)?

Comment: We've been using it live since the middle of October. Its designed to work with Django only (as this is what all our web apps use). Because of the number of long running tasks running through our Django apps, which are very sensitive to end user inputs, a key part of our use case is to be able to write the logs to the project DB so that they can be tracked and debugged easily

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ guys recommend **Pika** library: https://github.com/pika/pika
You can find simple and intuitive examples on their website: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

Comment: For anyone that stumbles on this: We tried to roll our own job queue at $DAYJOB from pika and I am now exploring libraries to replace that system.

Comment: Pika is not a task queue by any means - it is client library, which is a lot simpler (and can be used to implement custom task queue).