# Django how to manage long background process?

Tags: python, django, celery

I Django newbie and struggle with right decision about background process management. I have a task: unregistered user upload a file then I have to parse it and do some stuff which takes 30-50 sec depends on file.

Firstly, I thought just call function from view before render. This function can manage data using additional classes and so on. Then it just returns a result to a variable and render send it to a template.

example:

```
result = file_handle_function(request.FILES['file'])
return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': form, 'result': 'result'})
```

Secondly, I have read about celery a little, but I think it fits more for authenticated user. Though I'm going to make auth system later.

Which way I should choose? Any suggestions, links, criticism are welcome =)

Comment: Celery has nothing to do with authenticated users. It is absolutely the way to do long-running tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

First off it is not really a good idea to accept file uploads from unregistered users. This approach has many flaws some of which could be very worrisome. I am not sure your first way would work the way you imagine it. I would recommend celery or at least something similar. Celery works well (though it can be a pain), is well supported, its free and you can find my answers to questions about it. Here is a note about [security](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/security.html) in celery incase you decided to stick with unregistered user uploads, here is a question with some possible [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517613/python-task-queue-alternatives-and-frameworks) to celery and here is an article about building your own [task](https://testdriven.io/developing-an-asynchronous-task-queue-in-python) queue.