# Python - Handling concurrent POST requests with HTTPServer and saving to files

Tags: python

I have the code below that I would like to use to receive POST requests with data that I will then use to print labels on a label printer. In order to print the labels I will need to write a file with print commands and then do a `lp` command via the command line to copy the file to the label printer.

The problem I have is that multiple people could be printing labels at the same time. So my question is do I have to change the code below to use `ThreadingMixIn` in order to handle concurrent POST requests or can I leave the code as is and there will only be a slight delay for secondary request in a concurrent scenario (that is any further requests will be queued and not lost)?

If I have to go the threaded way how does that impact the writing of the file and subsequent command line call to `lp` if there are now multiple threads trying to write to the same file?

Note that there are multiple label printers that are being accessed through print queues (CUPS).

```
import json
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        try:
            result = json.loads(body, encoding='utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            response = BytesIO()
            response.write(b'This is POST request. ')
            response.write(b'Received: ')
            response.write(body)
            self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())
        except Exception as exc:
            self.wfile.write('Request has failed to process. Error: %s', exc.message)

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to use unique file name?
In this way you are sure that there will be no names clash.
Have a look on https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html , consider NamedTemporaryFile function. You should use delete=False, otherway the file is deleted imediatelly after close() .

Comment: This does not answer any of my questions

Answer (score 0):

according to your question what I understand is that you have only one label printer and you have multiple producers who try to print labels on it.

So even if you switch to a multithreading option you will have to synchronize threads in order to avoid deadlocks and infinite waiting,

So my best take is to go with a builtin python data structure called [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

> The queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads. The Queue class in this module implements all the required locking semantics. It depends on the availability of thread support in Python,

Even though its a multi-consumer, multi-producer queue I suppose it will still work for you like a charm.

**So here is what you need to do**

1. Your server receives a request to print the label,
2. do the necessary processing/cleanup and put it in the queue
3. A worker thread pops the items from the queue and executes the task

or if you would expect the system to be big enough, here are some links, but steps would be same as above

- [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) - A scalable message broker (simply put a queue)
- [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) - A python package for popping items from a message broker such as rabbitmq and executes it

Comment: I have multiple label printers. I've had a look at RabbitMq and Celery before but found them too complex to understand. My question really is whether I can avoid threading. Are you saying I can't?

Comment: `>I have multiple label printers`. in this case, you should go with a message broker system such as rabbitmq, and celery. And if you use these then thread management is out of the question. Which saves much pain in the future

Comment: maybe you can take a look at these alternatives for celery https://stackoverflow.com/q/46517613/2693543

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "if you use these then thread management is out of the question"

Comment: these == Rabbitmq and celery, Because they manage the threads themselves, you dont need to manually create threads and all

Comment: Which is simpler and is there a simple introduction somewhere? Do they replace my python httpserver?

Comment: Don't know about any simple introductions, maybe some google and youtube? will post any links if I get some

Comment: So are you saying I definitely need all this complication, since the standard HttpServer will just loose concurrent requests?

Comment: servers are supposed to handle multiple requests, but the issue is that printers take time to print the label, so each of your requests has to wait till the previous one completes printing, since there are no other threads to handle them as soon as they arrive. Which can cause timeouts, and long delays, So if you want to avoid multithreading for httpserver, better to use queues.

Comment: Surely if I put an `&` after my `lp` command it would start the print in the background via the print server queue and it would return very fast. The only thing I need to be sure of is that it won't loose requests with the non-threaded `httpserver`.

Comment: If you are sure that the printer returns fast, and as I said earlier `servers are supposed to handle multiple requests, ` and thus you should be fine,. Still I wonder how do you distribute the tasks among multiple printers

Comment: The post data will identify the printer to be used and the python `httpserver` would then route it to the appropriate printer queue. Was hoping for more than "should be fine".

Comment: Maybe you can run some load testing with it, https://locust.io/ . much better than my opinion though :P