# How to send weekly scheduled emails in Django

Tags: python, django, function, email

I like to send scheduled emails for my users every Fridays.
I'm using Pythonanywhere so I can't use Celery because PA can work with it. I like to use PA's Task function that can't schedule weekly tasks so it should check every day if it is Friday.
I started to write a function but I'm not so experienced and stuck. I don't know how to write the function if it does not have any html where I hit a button to trigger the function.

I made a `weekly_email_mm.py` file in my project directory:

```
import datetime
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render

today = datetime.date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()

def send_mm_email(???):
    
    subject = 'Hello'
    message = 'Hi there'
    
    if (weekday == 4):
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'something@from.com',
            ['user@xy.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
        print('Friday, mails sent')
    
    else:
        print('Not Friday')    
    
    return render(???)
```

Thank you in advance if you can help me out!

Comment: can you check https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: This answer may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517613/python-task-queue-alternatives-and-frameworks

Comment: If you want to use it as a PythonAnywhere's Scheduled task and have access do your Django web app stuff, I'd recommend writing it as a management command that can be run as a task with `manage.py`. I don't think you need to render anything, and as a scheduled task it will run automatically, so you don't need to hit any buttons as well.

Comment: Yes, thank you! You both wrote me good stuff :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use django-q,

```
https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
```

it is easy to use and comes with django admin panel integration,
you have to separately run qcluster server and use crontab field to create cron job.To create a job at every friday at 11:00 .use

```
0 11 * * 5
```

on crontab field in django admin panel or you can also create through code, follow the tutorial.