# How to handle network errors when saving to Django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django `.save()` execution that loops at `n` times.
My concern is how to guard against network errors during saving, as some entries could be saved while others won't and there could be no telling.
What is the best way to make sure that the execution is completed?

Here's a sample of my code

```
# SAVE DEBIT ENTRIES
for i in range(len(debit_journals)):

    # UPDATE JOURNAL RECORD
    debit_journals[i].approval_no = journal_transaction_id
    debit_journals[i].approval_status = 'approved'
    debit_journals[i].save()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/
Wrap it into transition. That way you guarantee that all data is saved or none, and that's one of the ways of protecting db/data integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) / [`bulk_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) to execute a single DB query, or use [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/topics/db/transactions/) as decorator for your function so that any error on save will rollback your database before your function was run.

Try something like below (I suppose your model name is `DebitJournal` and `debit_journals` is a list).

```
for debit_journal in debit_journals:
    debit_journal.approval_no = journal_transaction_id
    debit_journal.approval_status = 'approved'

DebitJournal.objects.bulk_update(debit_journals, ["approval_no", "approval_status"])
```

If `debit_journals` is a `QuerySet` you can also try

```
debit_journals.update(approval_no=journal_transaction_id, approval_status='approved').
```

Comment: Can you please show a sample of how you'd use it on the code above? I have never heard of bulk_create

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you call a network error, if it's between the user and the django application or between the django application and the database. If it's only between the user and the app, note that if the request has been sent correctly even if the user lose the connection afterward the objects will be created. So a user might not have the request response, but objects will still be created.

If it's between the database and the django application some objects might still be created before the error.

Usually if you want a "All or Nothing" behaviour you should use manual transaction as described there: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/

Note that if the creation is really long you might hit the request timeout. If the creation takes more than a few seconds you should consider making it a background task. The request is only there to create the task.

See [Python task queue alternatives and frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517613/python-task-queue-alternatives-and-frameworks) for 3rd party solutions.

Comment: Transaction between Django and the database. Sometimes I lost connection and I later discovered not all the objects were created. I'm talking about 500 records or more in the loop. That code is just a clipping of the entire code. The loop also includes sending emails and other things for each iteration. The tasks is not long as most times, it is completed without issue. But sometimes it doesn't, like when someone turn off or reset a modem thereby losing Network signal

Comment: Read about db transaction, that should solve the issue. Also you a a previous answer mentioned you can use `bulk_create` to reduce the db load.